# Git tracking to wrong local directory

Tags: linux, git, github

I created a new directory 438-healthme and cloned a repo into it.

When I index into that directory on the `master` branch and run a `git status` it lists all of my computer's files as untracked (see screenshot).
It seems like I set up git wrong a few years ago--is there a way to fix this?

[image: git status screenshot]

Comment: Is there a `.git` folder in your user's home directory? If so it's treating your entire home directory as a repo. Just delete that `.git` out of there and it may start behaving.

Comment: Change the remote to point to the new repo: `git remote set-url origin <remote url>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try again, removing that folder, and recreating it with:

```
git clone https://url/remote/repo 438-healthme
```

Then, in `438-healthme`, there should be a `.git` subfolder, which means a `git status` (in the newly created `438-healthme` folder) will show you files only from `438-healthme`.

Answer (score 0):

You must have run `git init` in a folder. You need to find it and run `rm -r .git`.